# is using 2 sch40 45 elbows the same as using a single 1-1/4" DWV elbow

Tags: drain-waste-vent

I am hooking up a Saniflow toilet that allows a sink to drain into it. The sink is 1-1/4 and the saniflow is 1-1/4 so I cant use anything but 1-1/4" lines. I cannot find any 1-1/4 DWV elbows locally. I am wondering if it is ok to use 2 sch 40 45 deg fittings in place of a 90 degree DWV elbow at 1-1/4".

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this question is no, you cannot use a normal sch 40 45 in a DWV system. Section 706 of the IPC prohibits it.

Comment: Other than "that's the code" what is the reason for this prohibition?

Comment: The reason it is prohibited under code is that the internal structure of the standard 45 elbow has an internal ridge. Under flow with solids this ridge would build up those solids and eventually cause a clog.